# Cannot drop an unnamed column in a csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to drop a unnamed column from a dataframe created from a CSV but it won't drop.

```
for m in mlist: #Loop through each month
    print('Running merge for '+str(m)+' collecting csv files...')
    csvlist = [i for i in glob.glob(str(m)+'2019_G*.{}'.format('csv'))] #List all the CSVs of each month
    month_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv) for csv in csvlist])
    month_csv = month_csv.astype({unique_gridid:'int'})
    month_csv = month_csv.set_index(unique_gridid)
    month_csv.columns.str.match("Unnamed")
    month_csv.loc[:,~month_csv.columns.str.match("Unnamed")]
    month_csv.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
    print(month_csv)
```

Console still shows the unnamed column in the print output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the following call:

```py
month_csv.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
```

The `drop` function has a `inplace` parameter that, by default, is equal to `False`. Therefore, the function returns a new dataframe with the dropped column. You have two options:

```py
month_csv.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

or

```py
month_csv = month_csv.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
```

Comment: I didn't see that mentioned anywhere in the information sources I was following, tank you! It dropped the field.

Comment: You may not believe me, but I often do the same mistake, and you know it's not an easy one to find in a long notebook )